Mongodb aggregate multiple collections super slow
New to Mongo so bare with me, but cannot figure out best (fast) solution.
I have three different collections: Shipments, Tracking, Messages
I'm trying to join two simple fields from the Tracking and Messages collections to a list of shipments.
Collections:
Tracking
{
    shipment: {
        id: XXX
    },
    enabled: true,
    ...
}

Messages
{
    shipment: {
        id: XXX
    },
    messages: [
        0: {
            isRead: false,
            origin: 'driver'
        },
        1: {
            isRead: false,
            origin: 'driver'
        },
        2: {
            isRead: true,
            origin: 'driver'
        }
    ],
    ...
}

Shipments
{
    _id: XXX,
    ...
}

When I pull list of shipments I need to be able to add the 'enabled' field from the Tracking collection and a 'unRead' count from the Messages collection from the messages array of subdocuments to each shipment based on the shipments ID so each shipment record looks something like:
{
    _id: XXX,
    trackingEnabled: true,
    unreadCount: 2,
    ...
}

I've tried every aggregate feature that I could find and I've accomplished it pulling what I need except it's incredibly slow. Pulling 50-60 records takes 8-9 seconds which is painful.
Here's a pipeline I've used that works but is insanely slow.
I've tried many variations including simple projection and filtering, and I cannot get anything speedy to filter out the messages array. Even just pulling just the Tracking with $lookup causes 2-3 extra seconds.
Any suggestions on another way to accomplish this or am I doing this wrong?
I would prefer to do this in one query vs looping the shipments and querying each collection separately, as that also takes too long.
[
        {
            $match: {
                active: true,
                deleted: false
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'messages',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'shipment.id',
                let: {
                    shipmentID: '$_id'
                },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $unwind: '$messages'
                    },
                    {
                        $match: {
                            'messages.isRead': false,
                            'messages.origin': 'driver'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $sortByCount: '$messages.isRead'
                    }
                ],
                as: 'unreadCount'
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'tracking',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'shipment.id',
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $project: {
                            'enabled': 1
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: 'trackingEnabled'
            }
        }
    ]


In the above-provided aggregate query, there seems to be lot of $lookup stage, which is generally a loop that takes an _id from the current collection and compares it with the foreign collection. These are not as efficient as SQL joins. To avoid performance overload, use proper index , pagination use $skip & $take.
Then, if your collection have huge data with each document, consider using $project stage after each $match or $lookup to take only necessary data, which will reduce the amount of data being carried to each stage.
Below are the reference link to do the above optimization:
Index - Index type in mongoDB
$project - MongoDB Query optimization
Note: MongoDB also generally suggests duplicating the data, which is frequently required by some collections, to avoid more lookups.

Is there a better way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do without $lookup?

Avoiding, $lookup for the above use-case is quite challenging since there are lot of dependent data in other collections, $lookup is the only way to fetch these data you can either denormalize the data in the other collection within the shipments collection which us also recommeneded by mongoDB, else follow the above mentioned optimization steps, thanks.

As I'm still new to Mongodb, what fields would be best indexed in the Messages and Tracking collections? I already have shipment.id indexed in these two collections and the queries are still very slow.
